# How do I build a three-phase common mode choke in Matlab simulink?

Tags: matlab, common-mode-choke

How do I build a three-phase common mode choke in Matlab simulink? Should I use the mutual inductor?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use [Three-Winding Mutual Inductor](https://www.mathworks.com/help/physmod/elec/ref/threewindingmutualinductor.html).

Ideally the coefficients of coupling will be \$K_{12} = K_{13} = K_{23}\$ = 1.0.

[image]

Be sure to pay attention to the dots indicating 'polarity' of the coils.